# Pass function as parameter to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters, callback

I have a generic function which queries some REST endpoint and calls back a different function once the result is received:

```
function ajaxLoadMovieById(id, callback) {
    $.getJSON(
        'https://example.com/rest/v1/film/' + id,
         function(data) { callback(data); } 
    );
}
```

I call it like so:

```
ajaxLoadMovieById(movieId, function(movie) { ajaxOnLoadMovieComplete(movie); } );
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. I'm getting a type-error on the line which contains 'callback(data)':

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
```

However 'callback' is a valid function with matching signature. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this the exact code causing the problem? Superficially, this looks valid. `console.log` `callback` to see what it is.

Comment: And you might as well give `callback` directly to `ajaxLoadMovieById` instead of wrapping it in another function.

Comment: Thx. The error was happening because I was calling the function from a different location with no callback-argument (yet). It's working as expected now. I'm new to JS so I thought I was missing something. The posted code is valid. Time for a break.

Comment: ajaxOnLoadMovieComplete  probably expects a callback as a second param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more modern approach would be use the promise returned by `$.getJSON` instead of passing in a callback:

```
function ajaxLoadMovieById(id) {
    // return the promise
   return  $.getJSON('https://example.com/rest/v1/film/' + id);
}

ajaxLoadMovieById(movieId)
   .done(ajaxOnLoadMovieComplete)
   .fail(function(){// or add this to `$.getJSON` in function
     //do something if request fails 
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this please

```
function ajaxLoadMovieById(id, callback) {
    this.callback = callback
    this.id = id
    $.getJSON(
        'https://example.com/rest/v1/film/' + this.id,
         function(data) { this.callback(data); } 
    );
}
```

Or this:

```
$.getJSON('https://example.com/rest/v1/film/' +id)
.done(funtion(data) {
   callback(data); // or another function
 }).fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  });
```

Comment: not sure what you think `this` is. It's not what you want it to be unless `new` gets used. Also doesn't change anything that gets passed to `$.getJSON` other than adding unnecessary code

Comment: The *"Or this"* version is also syntactically incorrect

Comment: @charlietfl I use to use this for the callback and it works well. I the second example is from documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: `done()` expects a function not the result of a function. You are invoking `callback` incorrectly. As for the first one `this` is probably `document` or `window` and can cause hard to chase bugs using it

Comment: @charlietfl I edit my answer it was a mistake to direct use the callback before the function is the .done()